# create share library with WiringPI

Tags: java, gcc, java-native-interface, wiringpi

I want create a shared library, because I need this for JNI.

I have two files

PiezoSpeaker.c

```
#include "PiezoSpeaker.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <softTone.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_PiezoSpeaker_tone__I
(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobject, jint khz) {
wiringPiSetup();
softToneCreate(29);
softToneWrite (29, khz);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_PiezoSpeaker_tone__II
(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobject, jint khz, jint duration) {

}
```

and

PiezoSpeaker.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class PiezoSpeaker */

#ifndef _Included_PiezoSpeaker
#define _Included_PiezoSpeaker
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     PiezoSpeaker
 * Method:    tone
 * Signature: (I)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_PiezoSpeaker_tone__I
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint);

/*
 * Class:     PiezoSpeaker
 * Method:    tone
 * Signature: (II)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_PiezoSpeaker_tone__II
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

I compile this with gcc

```
gcc -c -fPIC -I"/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/include/" -I"/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/include/linux" -IwiringPi -Ipthread PiezoSpeaker.c

gcc -shared -o share.so PiezoSpeaker.o
```

I become the error, that the symbol is undefined. The gcc command is wrong, because it does not include the wiringPi Library. How can I link the library, that the WiringPi Lib is included?

Comment: `-lWiringPi` ? You may need a `-L` argument to tell the linker where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of WiringPi you are using and how you built and installed it, the call could change. 
Assuming you are on a Rasberry Pi with [WiringPi - github](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi) (not the deprecated version but the unofficial mirror) and you have cloned the repo locally into your Rasberry Pi.

```
cd WiringPi
./build 
# add /usr/local/lib to /etc/ld.so.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

Above is take from [WiringPi INSTALL](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi/blob/master/INSTALL)

Then for you compilation line you would need

```
gcc -c -fPIC -I"/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/include/" -I"/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/include/linux" -lwiringPi -pthread -lrt -lm PiezoSpeaker.c
```

1. -lwiringPi  -- gets you wiringPi
2. -lrt and -lm  -- take care of linking to dependencies within wiringPi itself